# Visualforce Page with SelectList for Controlling Field

Tags: visualforce, selectlist

I have a visualforce page that is used for updating opportunities.  I have created a SelectList to control what values are displayed in the stage field (depending on the current stage's value)

The problem I have is that I have a dependent picklist that needs to be on the page at a certain stage.

When I only have the selectList on the page, I get an error that the controlling field needs to be on the page.

How can I continue to use my select list to control the values that display in Stage without getting an error that I need the controlling field on the page?

I got the stage field to work by using the following code:

```
<apex:inputField id="slStageInput" value="{!stopLossOpp.o.StageName}" style="display:none" label="" />
                                        <!-- custom stage field with limited values -->
                                        <apex:selectList value="{!tempslstage}" size="1" styleClass="required" >
                                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!SlStages}"/>
                                             <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!SyncSlStage}" reRender="SlOutcome"/>    
                                        </apex:selectList>
```

However, now, my dependent picklist is not getting updated.

thanks!!

Fred

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to either use Apex to enforce the dependency and forego the use of apex:inputField, or you'd have to use JavaScript in order to implement the stage change logic.

Comment: Thanks for responding!  I found a suggestion to add the input field with style="display:none"  I will edit my original post with the code.  That resolved the original issue.  However, I now have an issue where the dependent picklist is not getting updated after I update my select list.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!